# Azure Data Factory - Inner Activity Failed In For Each

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have used a look up activity to pass the value to the for each iteration activity. The output values from Lookup is generated from a SQL table. Once the iteration starts if one of the activity inside the for each fails, the for each iterator tries to run it for the number of times, the lookup output value is available. How do I come out of the loop? I have removed the records from the SQL table, to come out of the loop, but the loop continues to run. How can I clear the For Each Items set when an inner activity fails?

REgards,
Sandeep

Comment: Hi Sandeep T, For Each active doesn't support break for now even if the internal active failed. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the for each loop with the until activity. The input for the until activity was a SQL query which returns the count of records from the table where the file names are copied and a variable value. Used the @greater expression with Variable value, and lookup activity value. Inside the loop created logic to increment the value of the variable using a temp variable and add expression. If an expression fails, marked the variable value greater than the lookup output value.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I clear the For Each Items set when an inner activity fails?**

No, we can't. For Each active doesn't support break for now even if the internal active failed.

Many users have post same questions in stack overflow and [Data Factory feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory):
[image]

It' voted up 31 times but still with no respond of the Data Factory Product Team.

Ref: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39673909-foreach-activity-allow-break

**Update:**

Congratulations that you have found a solution for you scenario:

"Now used an until activity by comparing the variable values and count of files out put from a lookup activity to resolve the issue."

I post it in answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Leon yue, I have voted for it now. Now used an until activity by comparing the variable values and count of files out put from a lookup activity to resolve the issue.

Comment: @SandeepT Congratulations that you find a solution!  Can I add it to my answer? You can mark it as answer.. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Sure Leon Yue, If an activity fails, we should update the variable value to a greater number than the lookup output value